# Apache Rewrite or proxy

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, plone, zope, mod-proxy

I have an Apache server running on my machine (port 80)
I have a Zope server running on my machine (port 8080)

i want all users, irrespective of domain (lets use www.example.com for now) to be pushed to the zope instance, seamlessly

IE
if i type into my browser
http://www.example.com/mysite

it will display the effects of
http://www.example.com:8080/mysite

**BUT**

i want the URL to still say
http://www.example.com/mysite

(sub-)domain should be irrespective, as will have 2 or 3 domains pointing to the same server

am i supposed to be looking at mod_rewrite or mod_proxy?

I have the mod_rewrite half working,l but it changes what is in the browser?

currently trying

```
RewriteEngine on    
RewriteRule ^($|/.*) http://localhost:8080/$1 [P]
```

but getting server 500

Connecting using "http://localhost/mysite"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Zope supports your scenario out-of-the-box with some special rewriting, using a `VirtualHostMonster` flags in the path. This ensures that any URLs generated by Zope (and by extension, Plone) are correct for proxied requests as well.

You should use *both* `mod_rewrite` and `mod_proxy`, they'll be working in concert.

To make creating the right rewrite URLs easier, someone built an excellent [RewriteRule Witch](http://betabug.ch/zope/witch/). Plugging in your specific example outputs:

```
RewriteRule ^/mysite($|/.*) \
http://127.0.0.1:8080/VirtualHostBase/\
http/%{SERVER_NAME}:80/mysite/VirtualHostRoot/_vh_mysite$1 [L,P]
```

Thus, for any URLs rooted at `http://www.example.com/mysite`, rewrite these to be served from the server running on localhost port 8080, making sure that Zope generates URLs with the same root.

See the [detailed documentation on the VirtualHostMonster feature](http://wiki.zope.org/zope2/ZopeAndApache) on the Zope wiki for more details.

Comment: Shiny!  I didn't know about that Rewriterule Witch

Answer (score 3):

You can use either `mod_rewrite` with a `P` (proxy) rule or `mod_proxy` to do what you want.  Using `mod_rewrite` your configuration would look something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^/mysite/(.*) http://www.example.com:8080/mysite/$1 [P]
```

Using `mod_proxy`, your config would look like this:

```
<Location /mysite/>
  ProxyPass http://www.example.com:8080/
  ProxyPassReverse http://www.example.com:8080/
</Location>
```

Both accomplish approximately the same thing.  Using a `Location` block with `ProxyPass` makes it easy to apply other configuration directives to this path on the front-end server.

Comment: ok, i thought i understood but its not working, lets assume localhost, (as thats only place i can test at present) (sub-)domain should be irrespective, currently it returns a 404 (using the proxy solution) cheers

Comment: Put your actual configuration in the question, both for the frontend and whatever is listening on port 8080.

Comment: Apache docs recommend to use ProxyPass: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/avoid.html