# Apache mod_proxy with mod_rewrite Different Server Preserving URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, proxy, mod-proxy

I would like Apache to work in the following manner:

1. User types user1.app.com into the address bar.
2. DNS has a wildcard that forwards everything to SERVER1
3. SERVER1 has Apache running that will use a rewrite map to map user1 to IP address xxx.xxx.xxx.
4. Apache serves all content from xxx.xxx.xxx, while preserving the URL user1.app.com

I've attempted to do this several ways:

METHOD 1:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://xxx.xxx.xxx:port/ [P]
```

RESULT: Redirect Loop, the remote IP is accessed a handful of times (can confirm by looking at logs on remote server). SERVER1's logs show a repetition of the following:

```
proxy: *: found reverse proxy worker for http://xxx.xxx.xxx/
mod_proxy.c(1020): Running scheme http handler (attempt 0)
mod_proxy_http.c(1973): proxy: HTTP: serving URL http://xxx.xxx.xxx/
proxy_util.c(2011): proxy: HTTP: has acquired connection for (*)
proxy_util.c(2067): proxy: connecting http://xxx.xxx.xxx/ to xxx.xxx.xxx:80
proxy_util.c(2193): proxy: connected / to xxx.xxx.xxx:80
proxy_util.c(2444): proxy: HTTP: fam 2 socket created to connect to *
proxy_util.c(2576): proxy: HTTP: connection complete to xxx.xxx.xxx:80 (xxx.xxx.xxx)
mod_proxy_http.c(1743): proxy: start body send
mod_proxy_http.c(1847): proxy: end body send
proxy_util.c(2029): proxy: HTTP: has released connection for (*)
```

METHOD 2:

```
<VirtualHost *:801>
ServerName SERVER1

ProxyRequests Off

ProxyPreserveHost On

<Proxy *:801>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from localhost
</Proxy>

ProxyPass / http://xxx.xxx.xxx/
ProxyPassReverse / http://xxx.xxx.xxx/
LogLevel debug
</VirtualHost>
```

and

```
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://127.0.0.1:801/ [PT]
```

RESULT: 400 Bad Request
With method2, i can go to SERVER1:801 in my browser and everything works as expected.

Any help is GREATLY appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any updates on this? I believe this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11936922/apache-rewrite-or-proxy should be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution ended up being a combination of several different tools in apache:

- The use of a text file to map each subdomain to the appropriate IP
- The interpolation of environment variables to access the subdomain in the proxy redirection (had to use `ProxyPassInterpolateEnv On` and the `interpolate` keyword at the end of the `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse` statements)

Apache:

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On

<Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from localhost
</Proxy>

RewriteEngine On

ProxyPassInterpolateEnv On
RewriteMap subdomains txt:/directory/clients.txt
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.application\.com
RewriteRule ^ - [E=SERVER_NAME:${subdomains:%1}]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[^./]+)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R]

ProxyPass / http://${SERVER_NAME}/ interpolate
ProxyPassReverse / http://${SERVER_NAME}/ interpolate
```

Comment: what doesn clients.txt look like?

Comment: example file (each subdomain/ip pair is on its own line):  

subdomain 192.168.1.1  
subdomain2 192.168.1.2  
subdomain3 192.168.1.3

Comment: memo to self: if you use above, when looping back to the server you have this one, remember to explicitly define a serveralias in the VHOST, otherwise you have an infinity proxy-loop.

Comment: The second Rewrite (for the URI) kills the POST content of a request. I'm also not sure what it is trying to do? removing it worked for me.